# Non static method cannot be referenced from a static context al añadir una imagen a un JLabel

Tags: java, imagen

es que estoy intentando añadir una imagen a JLabel que declare public static 
pero cuendo utilizo esta linea de codigo
 `imagenFormulario.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/Butaca vacia.PNG")));`

donde imagenFormulario es el JLable que cree me tira el siguiente error

> non static method cannot be referenced from a static context

ya intente haciendo el JLabel no estatico y nada

y gracias por leer mi problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que tal, el error ése es porque estás tratando de usar algo no estático dentro de un contexto static, que imagino que debe ser el método main. Sin embargo paso a describirte otra opción para hacer lo que querés.

**Copiá** y **pegá** el código que te dejé abajo dentro de una clase que se llame **Panel**, a su vez posate sobre el **directorio principal** de tu proyecto, **luego botón derecho** y creá una **carpeta nueva**, ponele **"img"** o el que quieras pero hay que cambiar la ruta de la imagen en ése caso. Una vez terminado dale **"Run ass Java Application"** y si te anda analizá que está hecho, vas a ver lo simple que puede ser.

1) Declarás un **ImageIcon**.

2) **Lo instancias** dentro del método que quieras, un contructor etc.

3) **Creás unJLabel** y le **agregás a su constructor el ImageIcon** recientemente creado.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel label;

    /* Declarás un un ImageIcon que luego lo vas a crear en un método */
    private ImageIcon imagenFormulario;

    public Panel() {
        /* Creás el ImageIcon y le das la ruta de donde está la imagen */
        imagenFormulario = new ImageIcon("img/iconairplane.png");

        /* En el constructor del JLabel le agregás el ImageIcon recientemente creado */
        label = new JLabel(imagenFormulario);
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();

        BorderLayout borderLayout = new BorderLayout();
        frame.setLayout(borderLayout);
        frame.setTitle("Change JComboBox value");
        frame.add(panel);

        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 250, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    /* Método inicializador de App */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* Creamos el panel con el setVisible() en su constructor */
        Panel p = new Panel();

    }

}
```

**Te dejo un pantallazo con la estructura del mini proyecto por si la querés ver, y el JFrame ya lebantado y andando.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El siguiente código NO LO RECOMIENDO pero lo voy a usar para mostrarte porqué te tiraba ése error.**

Hagamos de cuenta que no usamos contructor y **que sí usamos un método static**, la **JDK** nos **va a pedir** que t**odas las variables** que usemos dentro del método estático sean static, o que no sean static, **pero que hayan sido definidas dentro del mismo**. Como todas las **variables** u **atributos** están definidas **afuera** del método tuve que colocarlas como **static** para que no me tire error de compilación.

Reitero esto **no lo recomiendo** si uno no está seguro de lo que está haciendo, mucho menos desde el método static main. Hay situaciones en que sí es muy útil pero en principio es mejor dejarlo acá creo.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel {

    private static JFrame frame;
    private static JPanel panel;
    private static JLabel label;

    /* Declarás un un ImageIcon que luego lo vas a crear en un método */
    private static ImageIcon imagenFormulario;

    /* Método inicializador de App */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* Creás el ImageIcon y le das la ruta de donde está la imagen */
        imagenFormulario = new ImageIcon("img/iconairplane.png");

        /* En el constructor del JLabel le agregás el ImageIcon recientemente creado */
        label = new JLabel(imagenFormulario);
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();

        BorderLayout borderLayout = new BorderLayout();
        frame.setLayout(borderLayout);
        frame.setTitle("ImageIcon");
        frame.add(panel);

        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 250, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

**Un útimo pantallazo, fijate que funciona igual, sin embargo los atributos son static y el método main también lo és.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @anferny Te dejo esta respuesta ojalá que te sirva, si soluciona tu duda fijate de marcar la pregunta como solucionada, arriba a la izquierda de mi respuesta.

Comment: men gracias ahi explica detalladamente todo

Comment: @anferny De nada, abrazos!!

Answer (score 0):

@berlot83
mira asi quedo, solo termino de travesear hahaha
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: bueno está bien, la pregunta del millón es... te anda?? abrazos